# GNUstep with QT Creator

Tags: objective-c, ide, qt-creator, gnustep

Is this possible at all? I don't have a mac but would like to learn the language and use an IDE which I like. Project Center and I don't get along too well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QT Creator has Objective-C support and has the flexibility to allow you to modify the build command used and specify which resulting file to run, so it could work very well as an IDE for GNUstep projects.

Comment: No problem. Project Center and I don't get along well either. :) Luckily, I've got Xcode.

Comment: By the way, do you know how to enable Objective-C support in QT? I'm having some trouble finding my way around this one, and unfortunately there's little documentation available.